# postgres and unexpected to_tsquery matching

Tags: postgresql

Consider the following:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (string text);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES
    ('the small but capable man'),
    ('the small and strong but capable man');
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE to_tsvector(string) @@ to_tsquery('small<->but');
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE to_tsvector(string) @@ to_tsquery('small<->capable');
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE to_tsvector(string) @@ to_tsquery('small<2>capable');
```

The first query returns both rows, when it should only return one (because `small but` only appears once as a full phrase). The second query query correctly returns no rows because `small` and `capable` are never next to one another. The third correctly returns only one because `small` and `capable` are within two of one another.

So question is: why does the first query return both strings? Is there something unique about words like `but` (or maybe `and`, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

ah, answer: this is using the `english` dictionary by default which excludes stop words by default (`and`, `but`, etc)-- to really match everything, I use the `simple` dictionary, e.g. `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE to_tsvector('simple',string) @@ to_tsquery('simple','small<->but')`.

[More here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html).